# Indirect references in VB.NET solution breaking build

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Project A references Projects B. Project B references Project C. Project A does not reference Project C.

This builds fine locally. However, on the build server it errors out because Project A does not reference Project C.

Error:

> error BC30009: Reference required to assembly 'ProjectC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' containing the implemented interface 'ProjectC.IFoo'. Add one to your project.

How can I catch this before committing?

Edit:
Here's more info on my issue: http://sstjean.blogspot.com/2006/11/msbuild-cant-find-secondary-references.html

Comment: What is the exact error you are receiving? Also, is it possible that you are building a different configuration on the build server?

Comment: Yes, it's building the Release configuration vs. the Debug configuration. I'll edit the OP with the exact error message.

Comment: Update: I built locally using the Release configuration and got the same build errors. Now to figure out the difference in Configuration...

Comment: Update: Those errors were actually not the same. VS can build the project, MSBuild can't. Details in the link I posted in the OP.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/586875/msbuild-4-0-incorrectly-processes-project-dependencies-specified-in-solution-file

Comment: Are you using MSBUILD 4.5? The problem and error you are getting was a bug in msbuild but has been fixed. Just curious because the article you referenced is from 2006.

Comment: This is like not wanting to hear an inconvenient truth.  The workaround is too simple to want to avoid it, just add the project dependency to C.  You really do have it, no point in expecting msbuild to do the heavy lifting to discover it.

Comment: @Hans, I'm fine with having to add the dependency. I'm not fine with VS not catching it while MSBuild does... breaking the build sucks. My example is simplified - in my actual scenario I have about 30 projects referencing Project B.

Comment: @SoftwareCarpenter - I'll check it out! If I use MSBUILD 4.5, can I still build on 4.0 framework?

Comment: .net 4.5 is an inplace upgrade of 4.0 so it will look like Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 . I would not want you to complicate anything by adding another variable x to the picture though.

Comment: How do I get this upgrade? When I view the details of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe it looks like the file version is 4.0.30319.17929. If I'm understanding your statement correctly I would expect the file version to be 4.5.*. I'm looking on my development machine that should have all version of the .NET framework and Visual Studio installed.

Comment: I guess the core question is: How do I know if I'm using MSBuild 4.5?

Comment: check the version of MsBuild.exe

Comment: See my previous comment.

Comment: Sorry...saw it after post. Looking right now at how to tell. Lol good question. Did you see my answer below? Are you still running into the problem?

Comment: Yes, we aren't able to install the .NET Framework 4.5 on our build server because it's windows server 2003. We're working on upgrading that so we can try the MSBuild 4.5 upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two things you can do as a best practice to ensure your projects are referenced correctly and MSBuild will be able to find your referenced projects correctly.

1. Use project references instead of referencing dll's. Create a folder called dependencies or libs and place any referenced dll's within this folder.
2. Check the build order and project dependencies tab for each project by right clicking project and selecting project build order. Ensure that every reference in your project is being built by that project.

MSBuild does not know what a .sln file is. MSBuild reads and parses the .sln file to determine the build order of projects. By having project references MSBuild will be able to traverse and build the projects in the correct order. See below link for more information.

This link also helps explain why you would see different behavior and how to catch it.

[Visual Studio Integration (MSBuild)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171468.aspx)

Within Visual Studio, the solution file and project build ordering are controlled by Visual Studio itself. When building a solution with msbuild.exe on the command line, MSBuild parses the solution file and orders the project builds. In both cases the projects are built individually in dependency order, and project to project references are not traversed. In contrast, when individual projects are built with msbuild.exe, project to project references are traversed.

When building inside Visual Studio, the property $(BuildingInsideVisualStudio) is set to true. This can be used in your project or .targets files to cause the build to behave differently.

Comment: I can't give you a +1 at the moment because your first sentence shows no difference in the behaviour to me. The rest of your answer fairly successfully attempts to correct that, though.

Comment: The sentence about using project referencing?

Comment: Currently your first sentence says "Visual Studio builds off of the solution file whereas MSBuild uses the .sln file as an input file that it reads to determine which projects to build." My interpretation of that is: "VS uses the .sln file whereas MSBuild uses the .sln file." As I said, the rest of your answer tries to distinguish the two scenarios.

Comment: I can try and clear it up. I am trying to state that Msbuild does not know what a .sln file is and therefore it reads the .sln and parses the projects to build. However within Visual Studio, the solution file and project build ordering are controlled by Visual Studio itself. This is why you may not be seeing errors in VS.

Comment: That edit works for me. However I'll need to confirm/research myself before giving you the +1. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project references and right click `Oracle.DataAccess` then go to properties and in properties page make sure that specific version is false and copy to local is set to true.